# Is there any way to nest two subqueries in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, view, subquery

I need to nest these two subqueries to work, anyone can help me ?
I made some comments but just to test, it doesn't work saying that there are two many arguments.
I need to make the changes to make it run.
I've tried to make a subselect in the second view containing the arguments and content of the first view but it doesn't work at all.

```
SELECT (SELECT
    --             b.dt_entrada
    --              extract (MONTH FROM d_entrada) mes_entrada
    --            extract (YEAR FROM b.dt_entrada) ano_entrada,
    --            SubStr(obter_desc_setor_atend(b.cd_setor_atendimento),1,255) ds_setor_atendimento,
    --            MIN(a.DT_AVALIACAO) dt_avaliacao,
    --            b.nm_paciente,
    --            b.ds_setor_leito,
    --            b.ds_setor_leito,
    --            ((MIN(a.DT_AVALIACAO) - b.DT_ENTRADA)*24) horas,
    --            CASE
    --            WHEN((MIN(a.DT_AVALIACAO) - b.DT_ENTRADA)*24) <=48 THEN 'Sim'
    --            WHEN((MIN(a.DT_AVALIACAO) - b.DT_ENTRADA)*24) >48 THEN 'Não'
    --            END AS result,
    --            CASE
    --            WHEN b.cd_classif_setor = 4 THEN 'Linha crítica'
    --            WHEN b.cd_classif_setor = 3 AND b.cd_setor_atendimento IN (57,37) THEN 'Linha cirúrgica'
    --            WHEN b.cd_classif_setor = 3 AND b.cd_setor_atendimento NOT IN (145,57,37) THEN 'Linha médica'
    --            WHEN b.cd_classif_setor = 3 AND b.cd_setor_atendimento = 145 THEN 'AVC'
    --            ELSE 'Outros'
    --            END AS linha_cuidado,
    --            b.nr_atendimento,
    --            b.cd_pessoa_fisica,
    --            b.cd_setor_atendimento,
    --            b.cd_classif_setor
              FROM hmdcc_eis_admitidos
              WHERE mes = mes_entrada
              AND ano = ano_entrada
              AND linha_cuidado = linha_cuidado
    )qtd_admitidos
    FROM (SELECT
                    b.dt_entrada,
                    extract (MONTH FROM b.dt_entrada) mes_entrada,
                    extract (YEAR FROM b.dt_entrada) ano_entrada,
                    SubStr(obter_desc_setor_atend(b.cd_setor_atendimento),1,255) ds_setor_atendimento,
                    MIN(a.DT_AVALIACAO) dt_avaliacao,
                    b.nm_paciente,
                    b.ds_setor_leito,
                    ((MIN(a.DT_AVALIACAO) - b.DT_ENTRADA)*24) horas,
                    CASE
                      WHEN((MIN(a.DT_AVALIACAO) - b.DT_ENTRADA)*24) <=48 THEN 'Sim'
                      WHEN((MIN(a.DT_AVALIACAO) - b.DT_ENTRADA)*24) >48 THEN 'Não'
                    END AS result,
                    CASE
                    WHEN b.cd_classif_setor = 4 THEN 'Linha crítica'
                    WHEN b.cd_classif_setor = 3 AND b.cd_setor_atendimento IN (57,37) THEN 'Linha cirúrgica'
                    WHEN b.cd_classif_setor = 3 AND b.cd_setor_atendimento NOT IN (145,57,37) THEN 'Linha médica'
                    WHEN b.cd_classif_setor = 3 AND b.cd_setor_atendimento = 145 THEN 'AVC'
                    ELSE 'Outros'
                    END AS linha_cuidado,
                    b.nr_atendimento,
                    b.cd_pessoa_fisica,
                    b.cd_setor_atendimento,
                    b.cd_classif_setor
            FROM    escala_nrs a,
                    atendimento_paciente_v b,
                     hmdcc_eis_admitidos c
            WHERE a.dt_liberacao is not NULL
                  AND a.ie_situacao = 'A'
                  AND b.nr_atendimento = a.nr_atendimento
                  --AND cd_classif_setor in (3,4) -- Excluído a pedido do cliente
                  AND b.dt_entrada BETWEEN To_Date('01/09/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND To_Date('30/09/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                  AND b.dt_cancelamento IS NULL -- Os atendimentos cancelados não são carregados
            GROUP BY b.dt_entrada,b.nm_paciente, b.ds_setor_leito, b.nr_atendimento, b.cd_setor_atendimento, b.cd_pessoa_fisica,b.cd_classif_setor
    )
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: You can use only scalar subquery in the select list. So you need to move your commented query to the `from` or `join` clause.

Comment: Also please avoid joining table via `where` clause, use `join` instead, because it is more readable and easy to debug.